# How to use the API java.util.concurrent.Future instead of creating threads explicitly in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have two threads running parallely in a java program as below:

```
// Threading
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            gpTableCount   = getGpTableCount();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}).start();

new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            hiveTableCount = getHiveTableCount();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}).start();

while(!(gpTableCount != null && gpTableCount.size() > 0 && hiveTableCount != null && hiveTableCount.size() > 0)) {
    Thread.sleep(5000);
}
// Threading
```

Both of them have same functionality. Below is the code from getHiveTableCount(). The other method is slightly different (a line or two) from the below one but the functionality remains the same.

```
public Map<String, String> getHiveTableCount() throws IOException, SQLException {
    hiveDataMap     = new HashMap<String, String>();
    hiveTableErrs   = new HashMap<String, String>();
    Iterator<String> hiveIterator = filteredList.iterator();
    Connection hiveConnection = DbManager.getHiveConnection();
    PreparedStatement hive_pstmnt = null;
    String hiveExcpnMsg;
    String ssn;
    String hiveMaxUpdTms;
    Long hiveCount;
    String gpHiveRec;
    String[] hiveArray;
    String[] hiveDetails;
    String hiveQuery;
    while(hiveIterator.hasNext()) {
        gpHiveRec   = hiveIterator.next();      
        hiveArray   = gpHiveRec.split(",");     
        hiveDetails = hiveArray[1].split("\\.");
        hiveQuery   = "select '" + hiveDetails[1] + "' as TableName, count(*) as Count, source_system_name, max(xx_last_update_tms) from " + hiveArray[1] + " where source_system_name='" + hiveArray[2] + "' group by source_system_name";
        try {
            hive_pstmnt             = hiveConnection.prepareStatement(hiveQuery);
            ResultSet hiveCountRs   = hive_pstmnt.executeQuery();
            while(hiveCountRs.next()) {
                hiveCount     = hiveCountRs.getLong(2);
                ssn           = hiveCountRs.getString(3);
                hiveMaxUpdTms = hiveCountRs.getTimestamp(4).toString();
                hiveDataMap.put(hiveDetails[1] + "," + ssn, hiveCount + "," + hiveMaxUpdTms);
            }
        } catch(org.postgresql.util.PSQLException e) {
            hiveExcpnMsg = e.getMessage();
            hiveTableErrs.put(hiveDetails[1] + ": for the SSN: " + hiveArray[2], hiveExcpnMsg + "\n");
        } catch(SQLException e) {
            hiveExcpnMsg = e.getMessage();
            hiveTableErrs.put(hiveDetails[1] + ": for the SSN: " + hiveArray[2], hiveExcpnMsg + "\n");
        } catch(Exception e) {
            hiveExcpnMsg = e.getMessage();
            hiveTableErrs.put(hiveDetails[1] + ": for the SSN: " + hiveArray[2], hiveExcpnMsg + "\n");
        }
    }
    return hiveDataMap;
}
```

These two threads run concurrently. I recently read online that:

> Future class represents a future result of an asynchronous computation
>   – a result that will eventually appear in the Future after the
>   processing is complete.

I understood the concept theoritically but I don't know how to apply the java.util.concurrent.Future api for the same above code instead of creating threads explicitly.
Could anyone let me know how can I implement multi threading on the methods: `getGpTableCount() & getHiveTableCount` using java.util.concurrent.Future  api instead of creating threads creating new threads like new Thread(new Runnable() ?

Comment: Have a look at `ThreadPoolExecutor` https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html

Answer (score 1):

You are submitting your tasks using the `Runnable` interface which doesn't allow your threads to return a value at the end of computation (and cause you to use a shared variable - `gpTableCount` and `hiveTableCount`).

The `Callable` interface is a later addition which allow your tasks to return a value (in your case, `Map<String, String>`).

As an alternative for working with threads directly, The Concurrency API introduces the  `ExecutorService` as a higher level object which manages threads pools and able to execute tasks asynchronously.

When submiting a task of type `Callable` to an `ExecutorService` you're expecting the task to produce a value, but since the submiting point and the end of computaion aren't coupled, the `ExecutorService` will return `Future` which allow you to get this value, and block, if this value isn't available. Hence, `Future` can be used to synchronize between your different threads.

As an alternative to `ExecutorService` you can also take a look at `FutureTask<V>` which is implementation of `RunnableFuture<V>`:

> This class provides a base implementation of `Future`, with methods to start and cancel a computation, query to see if the computation is complete, and retrieve the result of the computation
>
> A FutureTask can be used to wrap a Callable or Runnable object.

Answer (score 0):

At first, create executor service which suits your needs the best, for example:

```
ExecutorService ex = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
```

(more on executors: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html)

Instead of Runnable object, use Callable which is similar to runnable, but returns a value (more on callable : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/util/concurrent/Callable.html):

```
Callable<Map<String, String>> callable1 = // your Callable class
```

Type parameter should be the same as as the type which you would like to return as a result.

Next create a list of your tasks:

```
List<Callable<Map<String, String>>> tasks = new LinkedList<>();
tasks.add(callable1);
tasks.add(callable2);
```

and execute them:

```
List<Future<Map<String, String>>> results = ex.invokeAll(tasks);
```

above method returns when all tasks are completed (if I understand your case correctly, this is what you would like to achieve), however completed task could have terminated either normally or by throwing an exception.

at the end close the executor service:

```
ex.shutdown();
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using Java 8+ you may use `CompletableFuture.supplyAsync` for that in short like:

```
import static java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.supplyAsync;
.....
Future<Map<String, String>> f= supplyAsync(()->{
    try{
        return getHiveTableCount();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

`CompletableFuture.supplyAsync` will run it in default using `ForkJoinPool.commonPool()` it have also another overlap that taking `Executor`in its parameter if you want to use your own:

```
public class CompletableFuture<T>
extends Object
implements Future<T>, CompletionStage<T>
```

and it have.

```
public static <U> CompletableFuture<U> supplyAsync(Supplier<U> supplier)

public static <U> CompletableFuture<U> supplyAsync(Supplier<U> supplier,
                                                   Executor executor)
```